# How to marshall a set with jaxb?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have the following code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo
{

   @XmlElement
   private String id;

   ...

}
```

I would like to be able to marshal a `Set<Foo> foos` into:

```
<foos>
   <foo>
       <id>bar1</id>
   </foo>
   <foo>
       <id>bar2</id>
   </foo>
</foos>
```

Do I need a wrapper class? If so, how should it look? Are my annotations correct? How should the marhalling code look like (if you could illustrate this all, that'd be much appreciated)?

Comment: Did you tried with @XmlElementWrapper(name="foos") Set<Foo> foos;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to encapsulate any Collection use [XmlElementWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html)

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="foos")
@XmlElement(name="foo")
private Set<Foo> foos;
```

By the way you cannot directly marshall a Set so you have to include your Set inside your own class. So if you just want to marshall a set of Foo you have to write a bean like this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foos")
public class Foos {
    @XmlElement(name="foo")
    private Set<Foo> foo;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer: is it possible to not have a separate class which is just a wrapper around the `Set<Foo>`, as basically, that's what I'd be ending up with in your case...? Would you mind providing a complete example of how to wrap the `Set<Foo>` when marshalling, so that I don't need a separate class that contains just a `Set`...?

Comment: @carlspring unfortunately it's not possible to do this directly on Set you have to include it in your own class.

Comment: @carlspring you could also write a generic "marshallable" container see this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878229/unmarshalling-generic-list-with-jaxb So you could reuse this generic JAXB container for a Set of bars.