# Json-Jersey fails to unmarshall parametrized root List

Tags: java, json, list, jersey

Recently I tried write generic function that will convert json responses from an API to objects using jesrey-json-1.8. I found that it does work with properly with lists.
Can it be configured or jersey-json just can't deal with parametrized types?

This works:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class ListWrapper {       
    @XmlElement
    public List<Advertiser> advertisers; 
}

@Test
public void testListFromJson() throws ParseException, JAXBException {
    String str = "{\"advertisers\":[{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"adidas\",\"owner_id\":\"1\"},{\"advertiser_id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"bdidas\",\"owner_id\":\"2\"}]}";
    ListWrapper list = new ListWrapper();
    String json = str; //"{\"list\":" + json + "}";
    JSONJAXBContext jaxbContext = new JSONJAXBContext( list.getClass() );
    JSONUnmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createJSONUnmarshaller();
    list = unmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON( new StringReader( json ), list.getClass() );         
}
```

However, I need to use parametrized lists since I have several API calls returning lists: 'api/advertisers/all', 'api/permissions/all', 'api/campaigns/all' and etc, but this does not work:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class ListWrapper<T> {

    @XmlElement
    public List<T> advertisers; 
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void testListFromJson() throws ParseException, JAXBException {
    String str = "{\"advertisers\":[{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"adidas\",\"owner_id\":\"1\"},{\"advertiser_id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"bdidas\",\"owner_id\":\"2\"}]}";
    ListWrapper<Advertiser> list = new ListWrapper<Advertiser>();
    String json = str; //"{\"list\":" + json + "}";
    JSONJAXBContext jaxbContext = new JSONJAXBContext( list.getClass(), Advertiser.class );
    JSONUnmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createJSONUnmarshaller();
    list = unmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON( new StringReader( json ), list.getClass() );         
}
```

There is almost similar questions asked for XML 
(e.g. [Unmarshalling generic list with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878229)), but this solutions does not work for jersey-json, or perhaps just for my case where list is a root element:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class ListWrapper<T> {

  private List<T> items;

  public ListWrapper() {
    items = new ArrayList<T>();
  }

  public ListWrapper(List<T> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
  public List<T> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
}

String json =  "{\"items\":[{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"adidas\",\"owner_id\":\"1\"},{\"advertiser_id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"bdidas\",\"owner_id\":\"2\"}]}"; 
    JSONJAXBContext context = new JSONJAXBContext(Advertiser.class, ListWrapper.class);
    JSONUnmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createJSONUnmarshaller();

    ListWrapper<Advertiser> wrapper = (ListWrapper<Advertiser>)unmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON( new StringReader( json ), ListWrapper.class );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshalling generic list with JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878229/unmarshalling-generic-list-with-jaxb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No goo solution was found, so I did it in an ugly, but working way:
1. Remove brackets from start and end of json string
2. Split by ','
3. Pass over the array from (2) and make unmarshalling call